# [Conclave]How to support SSL in enclave?

Tags: corda, enclave

Hello Corda experts: I have a question about Conclave beta 3. I downloaded conclave SDK hello world project, and ran it according to conclave document successfully. But when I tried to use RestTemplate to access an external https API from the enclave, it is failed. And the error message is "**java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Default SSLContext not available**". Since the default JVM for enclave is Avian, I doubt that maybe Avian doesn't support SSL. Does any expert know the root cause and how to solve it? Thanks very much.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

At this time Conclave doesn't support outbound SSL connections. It's something we'd like to support and is a high priority but it must be done very carefully. For example, we will have to ship a root cert store with the enclave embedded in the binary (or a signed version that's injectable by the host), there are questions about how to handle expiry checking given that the host controls the clock, whatever credentials are used to access the external service (if any) need to be securely sealed and stored, it will only make sense to support OCSP Stapling as a form of revocation checking with all others needing to be disabled and so on.

You don't technically need us to solve these issues for you. You can load the SSLEngine and relay packets from it in and out of the host using the call mechanism. It'd be a bit awkward but should be possible.